# Derivation of Method of Substitution for Integration

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and $g(x)$ be a strictly monotonic, continuous, and differentiable function on $[a, b]$. Now, consider the integral $$\int^{b}_{a}f(g(x))dx$$ which can be written as the limit of the following sum (we know the limit of this sum must exist as $f(g(x))$ is a continuous function, and all continuous functions can be integrated): $$\sum^{n}_{v = 1}f(g(\xi_v))\Delta x_v$$ where $\Delta x_v$ refers to the v-th sub-interval of [a, b] and $\xi_v$ refers to an arbitrary point in the v-th sub-interval.

Since $g(x)$ is a strictly monotonic function there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the interval [a, b] on the x-axis, and an interval $\alpha \leq u \leq \beta$ of the values of $u = g(x)$, where $\alpha = g(a)$, $\beta = g(b)$. Thus, let $u_v$ be the corresponding point to $\xi_v$ i.e. $u_v = g(\xi_v)$ and $\Delta u_v$ be the corresponding sub-interval to $\Delta x_v$. Now, we can rewrite the sum as: $$\sum^{n}_{v=1}f(u_v)\frac{\Delta x_v}{\Delta u_v}\Delta u_v$$

Now, by the mean value theorem, we can write $\frac{\Delta x_v}{\Delta u_v}=\phi^{'}(\eta_v)$, where $\eta_v$ is a point in the interior of $\Delta u_v$ and $x = \phi(u)$ denotes the inverse function of $g(x)$. If we now select the value of $\xi_v$ in such way that $\xi_v$ and $\eta_v$ coincide, i.e. $\xi_v = \phi(\eta_v)$, $\eta_v = g(\xi_v)$, then we can re-write the sum as: $$\sum^{n}_{v=1}f(\eta_v)\phi^{'}(\eta_v)\Delta u_v$$
If we take the limit of this sum as $n \to \infty$, we obtain the expression: $$\int^{\beta}_{\alpha}f(u)\frac{dx}{du}du,$$ which is the formula for method of substitution.

This is my interpretation of Courant's proof for deriving the method of substitution, but I just wanted to make sure my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Since you pointed to a specific proof of the method of substitution, it would be nice if you can also include the link to the proof in your post.

Comment: The proof I referred to is in my physical textbook, and since the book is about 70-80 years old, I’m going to have a hard time providing you with a link.

Comment: I think at least providing which book it is or where can the original proof be found would be useful.

Comment: The book is Courant’s Differential and Integral Calculus Vol. 1 (Chapter 4, section is called Method of Substitution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is basically correct, but let me point out some fine points that you may have missed.  Courant assumes, not only that $g$ is differentiable, but also that its derivative is continuous and never 0.  Why?  To ensure that its inverse $\phi$ is continuously differentiable.  Simply knowing that $g$ is continuously differentiable is not enough to ensure that $\phi$ is differentiable.  For example, if $g(x) = x^3$, then $g$ is monotone and continuously differentiable, but the inverse is $\phi(u) = \sqrt[3]{u}$, which is not differentiable at 0.

To be sure that the limit of $\sum_{v=1}^n f(g(\xi_v))\,\Delta x_v$ is $\int_a^b f(g(x))\,dx$, we need to know that the maximum of $\Delta x_v$ (the *mesh* of the partition) approaches 0, and similarly for the Riemann sum used to compute $\int_\alpha^\beta f(u) \frac{dx}{du}\,du$.  Courant has a footnote in which he explains how to ensure this.  He chooses the partitions of the $u$-interval $[\alpha, \beta]$ first so that their meshes approach 0, and then he applies the uniform continuity of $\phi$ to conclude that the meshes of the corresponding partitions of the $x$-interval $[a, b]$ also approach 0.

I find Courant's use of the notation $\xi_v$ a bit confusing.  It sounds at first like he is fixing a choice of $\xi_v$ at the beginning of the proof, but then in the middle of the proof he says "If we now select the values $\xi_v$ in such a way that ..."  So the $\xi_v$ are not chosen until halfway through the proof, and the uses of the notation $\xi_v$ earlier in the proof have to be understood as referring to numbers that will be chosen, but have not yet been chosen at that point in the proof.

Finally, let me point out that, although Courant assumes that $g$ is continuously differentiable and its derivative is never 0, all he really needs is that $\phi$ is continuously differentiable.  Occasionally this makes a difference.  For example, consider this integral:
$$
\int_a^b \frac{dx}{(\sqrt[3]{x})^2+1}
$$
To solve it, we might let $u = \sqrt[3]{x}$, so $x = u^3$ and $dx = 3u^2\,du$.  The substitution gives us
$$
\int_a^b \frac{dx}{(\sqrt[3]{x})^2+1} = \int_{\sqrt[3]{a}}^\sqrt[3]{b} \frac{3u^2\,du}{u^2+1} = \left[3u - 3\tan^{-1}u\right]_{\sqrt[3]{a}}^{\sqrt[3]{b}}.
$$
This is correct, but it doesn't quite fit Courant's theorem.  In this case we have $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$, which is not differentiable at 0.  But $\phi(u) = u^3$, which is continuously differentiable everywhere, and that's all that is required in Courant's proof.

For a different explanation of this kind of substitution, see my book *Calculus: A Rigorous First Course*, Section 8.4.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I just wanted to clarify one thing. Courant also assumes in his proof that g(x) is strictly monotonic (he write monotonic in the book, but I have checked from earlier chapters that he uses the term monotonic to refer to strictly monotonic), and I assumed this is required to ensure g(x) is invertible everywhere in the interval under consideration. Would you say this condition is required? Additionally, if we do assume g(x) is strictly monotonic, doesn't that already tell us g'(x) > 0 or g'(x) < 0? Why does Courant add g'(x) is continuous and doesn't equal 0?

Comment: Yes, I think he assumes $g$ is monotonic so that it will be invertible.  That is certainly required for the argument he gives.  Perhaps if $g$ were not monotone one could break the interval into subintervals on which $g$ is monotone and work out the integral on those subintervals separately.  No, $g$ being monotone does not guarantee that $g'(x) \ne 0$.  For example, if $g(x) = x^3$ then $g$ is strictly increasing, but $g'(0) = 0$.

Comment: One more thing to clarify: can’t we just end the argument after we show $\Delta u_v$ tends to zero as $\Delta x_v$ tends to zero using uniform continuity, as that is what allows us to ensure that the sum: $$\sum^{n}_{v=1} f(u_v)\frac{\Delta x_v}{\Delta u_v} \Delta u_v$$ has a limit as $n \to \infty$ and this limit is the integral: $$\int^{\beta}_{\alpha} f(u)\frac{dx}{du} du$$ In other words, isn’t the last part with the mean value theorem kind of unnecessary?

Comment: No, you need the mean value theorem step.  To get $\int_\alpha^\beta f(u) \frac{dx}{du}\,du = \int_\alpha^\beta f(u) \phi'(u)\,du$ as a limit of a Riemann sum, you need a Riemann sum of the form $\sum_{v=1}^n f(u_v) \phi'(u_v)\,\Delta u_v$.  So you need to change $\frac{\Delta x_v}{\Delta u_v}$ into $\phi'(u_v)$, and the mean value theorem does that.